# List all files and import them in a small batch

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've tested some code I found and it works fine for my Access app but what I'm trying to achieve is:
count all in a folder (in this case) csv file and import them in a small batch e.g. 10 of 190 files
this is the code what is used

```
Sub LiveCheck()
    Dim Path, FilePathName, File, FileNameList() As String
    Dim FileCount As Integer, SQL_Append, SQL_Update As String
    Dim Numbers() As String

Const TARGET_TABLENAME As String = "Land_controle"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Path = "J:\Monitor\LIVE\"
File = Dir(Path & "*.*")


    While File <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileNameList(1 To FileCount)
        FileNameList(FileCount) = File
        File = Dir()
    Wend
    
    If FileCount > 0 Then
        For FileCount = 1 To UBound(FileNameList)
            FilePathName = Path & FileNameList(FileCount)
            DoCmd.TransferText transfertype:=acImportDelim, SpecificationName:="Land Import Specificatie", tableName:=TARGET_TABLENAME, Filename:=FilePathName, hasfieldnames:=True
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm stuck here, is there an easy or simplistic way?

Comment: Not really understanding what you want. If you want to import all 190 CSV files, what exactly do you mean by 'batch'? Or are there 190 files and only 10 are CSV?

Comment: If you want to import files in "batches" you may want to consider using a table to store imported files, so that when you loop the files in a folder you can check what has already been imported. But without clarification nobody will be able to help you. Note that `Path`,`FilePathName`,`File` are all actually `Variants` as you need to declare `Dim Path As String, FilePathName As String,File As String,FileNameList() As String`. And `Path` and `File` are bad names for variants - they are probably reserved words.